# Instead of racing I like to watch movies

Tags: wordplay, story, knowledge, steganography

I am not a great fan of racing. I never was. But one day I decided to see the race. The commentator was trying to keep up with the race's pace and did it quite well:

> The Black Horse of the event is leading the race. On the second position there is Golden Bull just after the leader...
>   But wait! The Dark Sky runs forth and takes the lead with its five little stars. And the big one of course.
>   The third position was taken by Double Caret...
>   And we have a new leader! The Olympics Runner, although today one of its bottoms is put at its tail and the other one is absent.
>   The third position has also been replaced by Thick Rhombus. Straight Age from position four struggles to take it over but where two quarrel the third wins - the third position is taken by Omega Juliet but not for long, as Silvermane Lion jumps forward and gets it.
>   Meanwhile the Golden Cross shines its way through to the fifth position.
>   Winged Minimalist falls to the second position just before finish as it is taken over by Lightning Circle.
>   Third place goes to Skewed Age.
>   Pacyfist broke its leg, so it ends up being the last (its twin did not take part in the race today).

When the last one crossed the finish line I felt I'd rather go to the cinema. Can you find out **what movie I wanted to see**?

NOTE: The puzzle may require a (very) little google work, so there is the "knowledge" tag.

HINT:

1. > The first thing to do is to find out what is the meaning of each "horse's" name (all fall to the same category).
2. > I believe the easiest one to start with is the Omega Juliet.

Comment: ROt13: Whfg fbzrguvat nobhg Gur Qnex FXl: Gung'f n zbivr sebz 2013. Abg fher vs guvf vf eryrinag.

Comment: @Mithrandir V jvyy abg fnl vs vg vf gur vagraqrq ersrerapr lrg.

Comment: @Downvoter Please comment to help me make this puzzle better :)

Comment: Is [tag:steganography] actually correct here?

Comment: @Rubio *Hidden data concealed in otherwise unsuspicious pictures, **text**, and/or audio.* sounds like this is exactly it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The horses' names refer to ...

> .. car brands, usually by describing their logos:
>
>  Black Horse — **Ferrari**
>  Golden Bull — **Lamborghini**
>  Dark Sky — **Subaru**
>  Double Caret — **Citroën**
>  Olympics Runner — **Audi** (has four rings, the Olympic flag has five)
>  Thick Rhombus — **Renault**
>  Straight Age — **Honda** (has an upright Aitch as logo)
>  Omega Juliet — **Alfa Romeo** (via Alpha/Omega and Romeo/Juliet)
>  Silvermane Lion — **Peugeot**
>  Golden Cross — **Chevrolet**
>  Winged Minimalist — **Mini**
>  Lightning Circle — **Opel**
>  Skewed Age — **Hyundai** (has a skewed Aitch as logo)
>  Pacyfist — **Mercedes** (logo looks like a peace symbol without the lower stem?)

With these replacements, ...

> ... and the positions as told in the commentary, we can get a letter from each horse:
>
>  1   **F**   **F**errari
>  2   **A**   L**a**mborghini
>  1   **S**   **S**ubaru
>  3   **T**   Ci**t**roën
>  1   **A**   **A**udi
>  3   **N**   Re**n**ault
>  4   **D**   Hon**d**a
>  3   **F**   Al**f**a Romeo
>  3   **U**   Pe**u**geot
>  5   **R**   Chev**r**olet
>  2    **I**    M**i**ni
>  1   **O**   **O**pel
>  3   **U**   Hy**u**ndai
>  L   **S**   Mercede**s**

And the film you went to see is:

> **Fast and Furious**.

Comment: About the two not-exactly-logo-like names: Olympics Runner - "*one of its bottoms is put at its tail and the other one is absent*" and  the "*Pacyfist broke its leg*". Otherwise this is the correct answer by all means :)

Comment: Oh, I'd seen the significance of the bottom at the tail, but didn't want to spoil the layout with a lengthy explanation. `:)` I didn't see the broken leg, though, and thought it had something to do with I being replaced by Y, because you can get the peace symbol by overlaying I and Y upside down and the Mercedes star only has the Y.

Comment: And you were right with your hint: Omega Romeo was the way in.